# How to set the integrated GPU as default on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, gpu, integrated-graphics

I would like to set the integrated GPU as default.
Currently, many Windows applications use the GPU dedicated, as shown in the attached image. Sorry for the Italian language in the image, however, you can see that the System, the Desktop Windows Manager, the Runtime process client-server and the Windows host shell experience are all using the dedicated GPU. Is there a way to set the integrated GPU as default? I would like to use the dedicated GPU only for certain kinds of software (like games).
My computer specs:
i9-10980HK (with UHD graphics)
GPU: nvivia RTX 3080 Laptop GPU 
Windows 10 Pro 21H2

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do you currently have the Intel display drivers installed?